# Auto redirect not working so PDT response is not coming for paypal rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, return, paypal-sandbox, paypal-pdt

I am sending $10 from my sandbox paypal account(with fake visa card) to my live paypal account. Once I pay the auto direct (auto return) is not working. Is there any issue because of the sandbox account?

Here is the parameters that I am sending on paypal page I am using Paypal SDk rest Api

```
values = {
            business: "info@eaglemovers.com.au",
            cmd: "_xclick",
            upload: 1,
            # return: "http://192.168.1.10:3000/",
                    invoice: id,
            amount: "10",
            item_name: "book",
            item_number: "1",
            quantity: '1',
                    currency_code: "AUD",
            # notify_url: "http://192.168.1.10:3000/"
        }
```

**I just need to send an email to the user once a payment is successful.Can anybody please tell how to get response that payment is successful or failed.**

Below is HTML form code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="accounts@freelanceswitch.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: do you turn on your auto return on your paypal account?

Comment: yes I have turned that on and provided return url but is not redirecting